# How to include descender height in automatic height calculation?

Tags: html, css

With line-height: 1 the descenders on the font will overflow the automatic height.

Here is a sample:

```css
body{
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
}
div{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="">gqpy</a>
  </div
</body>

</html>
```

I could use [How to calculate descender height in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180148/how-to-calculate-descender-height-in-javascript) to calculate the height and add padding manually, but I would like to use a pure CSS solution if it's possible.

Comment: The problem still shows up without the anchor element, it just makes it easier to see the problem.

Comment: there is not "space for the underline". The baseline is the line on which most letters like k, m, a etc.  are placed, however, there are letters like g, j, p etc. that go below the baseline, and they need this space. The `line-height` measures the height from the very lowest possible point to the very highest point any letter of the alphabet can possibly reach.

Comment: That makes more a lot more sense.  So the space is left for those letters.  I can see it now on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVpRYy.  I think I can find a way to fix it now.

Comment: Updated with the actual problem.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Is is what you mean ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKoYgL

```
ul { padding-left: 0}
li { list-style-type: none;  }
a {font-size: 70px; }
```

Remove the `overflow: auto;` on the `ul` style and you will not have a scrollbar on links.

Comment: That just makes it take longer to show up.  If you bump the font-size up to 30px the scrollbar appears.

Comment: Ok, now I see more clearer what you wants. Just edited my answer

Comment: line-height: 1 is part of the reset.css from http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.  It is there to help standardize css defaults between browsers.

The height on the li element is correct.  The problem is that the anchor element has space for text-decoration causing the overflow.

Comment: Ok then remove the `overflow: auto;` on the `ul` element : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKoYgL